# Javascript: When all buttons are clicked function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, button, click

Hello sir I'm practicing my vanilla javascript. I am trying to create a "Hangman Game" when the correct letters are clicked from the buttons.. You win. I have all these buttons in queryselector(letterA to letterZ).

The problem using this function.. `the winAlert = visible implements` when the `letterS` was clicked (last letter of "cautious").

So is there a way when you clicked all the letters of cautious in any order the `winAlert.style.visibility = "visible"` will be execute inside the function?

I've tried everything in the last hours.. `buttons.forEach`, slice etc. nothing works.

```
function youWonCautious() {
  var buttons = [letterC, letterA, letterT, letterI, letterU, letterI, letterO, letterS]
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var button = buttons[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

    button.onclick = function() {
      winAlert.style.visibility = "visible"

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `var button = buttons[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];` doesn't do what you think it eoes.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons don't automatically maintain any state about whether they were clicked. You can do this yourself using the `dataset` property of the button.

Then your function can test whether all the buttons have this property set.

Or maybe you can change your buttons to checkboxes, and use the `checked` property.

```js
function allButtonsClicked(buttons) {
  return buttons.every(b => b.dataset.chosen == 'true')
}

function youWonCautious() {
  var buttons = [letterC, letterA, letterT, letterI, letterU, letterO, letterS];
  buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.dataset.chosen = 'true';
    if (allButtonsClicked(buttons)) {
      winAlert.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global array in which log the alphabets clicked by the user.  check for the alphabets in the global array variable and answer array.
If matches Pass alert message else fail message to user.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).